# Returning Plain old XML with WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, rest

How can this be so difficult and why?  Returning simple XML with no Name Spaces and an XML decaration.  Creating the XML using XML Writer is easily done and if I output it to a file then great.  How on earth can you return the contents via WCF.  Using an XML Element is no good as you loose the XML declaration and using a string is no good as the output is wrapped up in a <string> element.  Can't return an XML Document as it can't be serialised.

I know that there are many posts on this site, but none answer the question.  I am using VB.NET (boy I wish I had the time to learn C#) and I cannot get the Data Contract to work either even using IXmlSerializer.  An example of the output I need to send back via WCF service is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <BookingResponse timestamp="" success="1">
<confirmation id="" track_code="" status="" notes="" tracking_url="" confirmed_at=""/>
 </BookingResponse>
```

Unfortunately the service I am sending to will not accept anything other than this plain XML.  The will not accept additional Name Spaces that WCF seems to put in all by it's self.

I am using the Online Rest Template for VB that is available for Visual Studio 2010.

Help! Please! someone must have an answer?

Here is some code:

```
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="BookJob", Method:="POST")>
        Public Function Create(ByVal XMLBooking As Stream) As Stream
            'DO SOME PROCESSING ON THE REQUEST - THIS ALL WORKS FINE.....

            Dim str As String

'This CreateResponseXML function creates a String version of the XML, which is built using XMLWriter.


       str = CreateResponseXML(True, vConfirmationID, sqlFuncs.BookingStatus("Confirmed"), "", "")

            Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
            Using streamWriter As New StreamWriter(memoryStream)
                streamWriter.Write(str)
                streamWriter.Flush()

                memoryStream.Position = 0

                Return memoryStream
            End Using

        End Function
```

To add to the hassel they have to use a secure connection.  I am using the Online Rest Template for VB that is available for Visual Studio 2010 which cuts down the entries in the web.config significantly compared to the normal one I see everywhere.  It looks like this
:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.vb file and the default endpoint 
            via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

  </system.serviceModel>



</configuration>
```

I tried returning a MemoryStream previous to this code, but the response they got was wrapped in a MemoryStream element and was gobbldegook (but this may have been due to the fact that I  ommited the transferMode="Streamed" entry in the web.config.  This version returns nothing at all.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WCFRestContrib](https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib) it has POX formatter (Plain Old Xml) which is clean and without any namespaces.

> The POX formatter uses the
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer, but unlike the
>   WCF REST Contrib xml formatter ([Discussed under Xml Formatter
>   Overview), does not serialize data contract namespaces or xml schema
>   attributes, it does not require namespaces to be specified in xml to
>   be deserialized and it does not require elements to be in a specific
>   order. This enables you to serve and accept very simple xml.

See [POX Formatter Overview](https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib/wiki/POX-Formatter-Overview)

Answer (score 1):

Use Stream as the return value.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did think of that.  Will the receiver be able to view the text within the stream if he's not using Microsoft tools?

Comment: @tim  Absolutely.  What you are returning is just a stream of bytes.  Don't forget to set the content-type header to the appropriate media type.

Comment: Hi Darrel, Have just had a response that they can't read the stream. I has using and returning a MemoryStream.  Is this my problem, How can I convert a Memory Stream to a normal Stream?

Comment: @tim Memory streams are fine.  I use them all the time.  Can you post some code showing how you are returning the stream?

Comment: Hi Darrel,  I have posted some code for you to have look at in my original post.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @tim  That looks good to me. Try removing the using.  It is possible that disposing the stream writer also disposes the stream.  You really don't need to dispose a MemoryStream as it is all managed memory.

Comment: I've tried that and am waiting the results.  There are two differences from when they were getting gobbldygook and nothing. 1. I was returning a MemoryStream and not a normal Stream, 2. I ommitted the transferMode="Streamed" from the web.config file, which is why I am assuming it was gobbldygook.  I'll let you know the results when I get them.

Comment: @tim  Did you try testing it with fiddler?  Fiddler will allow you to make the request and ensure that it returns a valid response.

Comment: Darrel - It worked!  Taking the Using away did the job.  Thank you so much you have saved my life. I'm too new to this site and don't have enough reputations to give you even 1 vote - I'd give 100 if I could.   If anyone else has this problem - USE A STREAM as posted in my code above, but use DIM on the TextWriter instead of USING.  Thank you once again.